# Decompression with Xarchive

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database I want decompressed.  I understand that the program to use is Xarchive, as it contains bunzip2.  Bur I get an error that I am supposed to find in "Store archiver output" which I don't know what is, and the machine cannot find it. The output folder is generated, but it is empty.

What do I do wrong, and how can I correct this error?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.02.